# How to create a window with all worksheets using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I want my Excel files to be easy to navigate. I have a lot of worksheets, and switching between them using PgUp and PgDn is not very convenient.

I found this command

`Application.CommandBars("Workbook Tabs").ShowPopup`

[image]

But if there are more than 15 sheets, it doesn't display all sheets. And if you click on "More sheets ...", then this window will appear:

[image]

Is there a way to display this window right away?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to display this window right away?

You mean like this?

```
Application.CommandBars("Workbook Tabs").Controls(16).Execute
```

Usage would be like

```
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count > 16 Then
    Application.CommandBars("Workbook Tabs").Controls(16).Execute
Else
    Application.CommandBars("Workbook Tabs").ShowPopup
End If
```

Comment: This works fine, but I'm also interested if there is a way to access this window directly. Because it also opens when you rightclick arrows of sheet selection in the lower left corner.

Comment: Directly as in? Click of a button?

Comment: I mean, this code accesses the sheet selection window via a pop-up with only 16 items. But is it possible to write code that opens only sheet selection window, regardless of the number of sheets?

Comment: The If condition takes care of that. Doesn't matter how many sheets are there, it will show you all.

Answer (score 1):

In case we have hidden sheets, the code posted by @Siddharth Rout might not show anything.( if we have >16 sheets but we have some hidden ones)

```
Public Sub showSheetList()
   With Application.CommandBars("Workbook Tabs")
      'MODIFY THE STRING "More Sheets..." to submit your local
      If .Controls(.Controls.Count).Caption = "More Sheets..." Then
          .Controls(.Controls.Count).Execute
      Else
          .ShowPopup
      End If
   End With
End Sub
```